# Htaccess ignored on live server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using a .htaccess file to use clean url's, Everything is working fine on my localhost, but on the production server my .htaccess is ignored..

I have an index.php entry point which requires the files needed.. But as you can see when you browse to
http://mindstretchscan.eu/overzicht , it's trying to load the required page directly. but not the index.php.

[http://mindstretchscan.eu?page=overzicht is working!](http://mindstretchscan.eu?page=overzicht) and it's the same page..

This is the top of my .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Pulling my hairs out on this one. Thanks!

Comment: have you double checked that mod_rewrite is enabled on your live machine?

Comment: Yep i called with support and it's enabled by default. Thank you

Comment: In that case, in the apache config file inside `<Directory "...">`, make sure that AllowOverride is set to 'All' and not 'None' so that the .htaccess file can be obeyed.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled

```
#sudo a2enmod rewrite

#/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

You also need to enable the use of .htaccess files by changing AllowOverride None to AllowOverride FileInfo. For the default website, edit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

And make sure you restart apache again.

Comment: I will contact server admins tech staff with your information. Thank you! and thank you @castis